# What is the correct javascript event for any text change in a text input control?

Tags: javascript, events, text, input, onchange

Whenever the text in an input control changes, I need to update some stuff immediately. But I can't seem to find the correct event for this.

- onchange only fires when you leave the input box (i.e. tab away or click outside).
- onkeypress fires *before* the change is made, and it fires on *any* key press (e.g. also cursor left & right which don't cause any text changes)
- onkeydown and onkeyup also fire on *any* key (even like Shift etc, which don't cause any text changes)

Also, none of these seem to fire when right-clicking + pasting from clipboard with the mouse. Or when changing the value from within JS (i.e. doing input.value = something from somewhere else).

Minimal example: http://jsfiddle.net/nggAm/

What should I do? I guess one way I might work around this (well, mostly) is setting ALL events to one generic event handler, caching the value there, and only do the actual update when the string is changed. But this feels kinda crappy. What's the *correct* way of doing this?

Comment: Unfortunately, [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events) are neither cross-browser nor recommended.

Answer (score 1):

For older browsers, you **do** need to set the input's onkeyup and onchange and onpaste.

But newer browsers have oninput, which is what you wish every browser had.

You can set all the events, and then remove everything but oninput if the oninput fires.

(But IE9 has a problem with passing input events if you are backspacing or deleting characters, so leave the key event just for that browser.)

**sample code-directing all events to one handler, removing if oninput fires**

```
F.text1.oninput= function(){
    F.text1.onpaste= F.text1.onchange= null;
    if(!document.documentMode) F.text1.onkeyup= null;
    F.text1.oninput= F.limiter;
    return F.limiter();
}
F.text1.onpaste= function(){
    setTimeout(F.limiter, 100);
}
F.text1.onkeyup= F.text1.onchange= F.limiter;
```